# Inserting to Binary Search Trees

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

So i need to define a destructive function BST insertbst(int i, BST t) that inserts i into BST t. That is, it modifies t to include i and returns the resulting tree. The running time must be O(height t).

I have come up with this version ... but gives me the following error's  ideone.com/xhxb6

```
BST insertbst(int i, BST t) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        return BSTmake(i, NULL, NULL);
    } else if (i < BSTkey(t)) {
        return BSTmake(BSTkey(t), insertbst(i ,BSTleft(t)), BSTright(t));
    } else {
        return BSTmake(BSTkey(t), BSTleft(t), insertbst(i ,BSTright(t)));
    }
}
```

The other functions used in my code can be found in: http://pastebin.com/TVYRE4Nd
Any suggestions to make it destructive, or to change it to avoid my heap error?

.h file: http://ideone.com/QeSTl

Test file: http://pastebin.com/9ca5i4My

Comment: It's really hard to tell what your actual question is. Perhaps you could clarify your post.

Comment: The code link requires login.

Comment: i basically want to make my function destrutive (modifies t) ... i seem to be have trouble getting my code to run without heap errors

Comment: Sorry, updated links and added test-file

Comment: What exact errors are you seeing and how are you seeing them?

Comment: I'm getting the following error's http://ideone.com/xhxb6, when i run my testfile

Comment: The specification makes this question much too localized.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `BSTmake()` like you are doing now as you are creating a new `BST node` everytime it is called, where as you can definitely be sure that the new node should only be created only once for each insert.

Now for the following two statements in `main`

```
BST x = BSTmake(2, (BSTmake( 1, NULL, NULL)), (BSTmake(3, NULL,NULL)));
BST y = insertbst(4, x);
```

I don't know your assumption about where `y` should be pointing to. In general, implementations of a BST would just call `insert` on their own, passing in the `node` to be inserted and the `root node`. You will see that using this approach makes code much simpler to comprehend. You'll have to change your second line as `insertbst( 4, &x)` to use this pattern.

You would then have to change the implementation of your `insertbst` as below:

- Pass the second argument as a pointer to the node pointer which represents the parent of the `newnode`.
- if `BST *t` is null, create a new node and assign the pointer to the node to point to it.
- if `i < BSTkey(t)` or `i > BSTKey(t)`, you need to call insertbst() recursively by passing the pointer to either the left subtree or the right subtree as the second argument.

This is what it may look like:

```
BST insertbst(int i, BST *t) {
    if (*t == NULL) {
        *t = BSTMake( i, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else if (BSTkey(newnode) < BSTkey(*t)) {
        insertbst( i, &t->left);
    }
    else {
        insertbst( i, &t->right);
    }
}
```

Also `malloc()` returns a `void *` which point to the allocated memory chunk. I am assuming `BST` is has been `typedef`ed something like `typedef struct bst_node * BST`. Hence you should change the `newnode` declaration as `BST newnode = (BST)malloc(sizeof(struct bst_node));`.

Comment: I added a .h file to clarify the typdef.. I'm confused, insertbst should consume a BST and a int ... and then add the int accordingly ? Why are we consuming a BST and a pointer?

Comment: Can you explain what should `BST y` be pointing to after the call to `insertbst()`?
BST itself is a pointer, and the second argument is to **save** the _address_ of a BST pointer, as we need to **change** the structure of the tree node where the insertion finally takes place. Think of it in this way: suppose if the tree is empty, after `insertbst` returns, your `BST x` should be pointing to the new node which was to be inserted. This is why the `insertbst` is defined as that.

Comment: i dont think BST should be pointing anywhere, the inputed BST should just be edited, so that the appropriate node is pointing to the newly added "i" node ... I need insertbst to consume an int and a BST thou ... is there no way to do that ?

Comment: You can do that but you would definitely have to pass the 2nd argument as a pointer to `BST` (which itself is a pointer to `bst_node`). I've updated the solution accordingly.

Comment: Yes it is, but you need to update the `left` or the `right` of the node where the new node finally goes. In the statement `*t = BSTMake( i, NULL, NULL);`, `t` has the address of the `left` or the `right` node where the parent passed the **Left** or **Right** pointer to contain the new node.

Comment: how come your not returning anything in your function ?

Comment: I dont think i can change the input types for my question that's why im confused .... I'm thinking to create a pointer to keep checkin for i<key or i>key of current BST pointing at and once i reach null i'll insert newnode? something like `BST newnode = BSTmake(i,NULL,NULL);
BST *temp = &t;`

Comment: Also what does the compiler error mean, `request for member ‘left’ in something not a structure or union` ?

Comment: You can take a look [at this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) about Binary Search Trees. I'm using the conventional method in my solution. Let me figure out how it can be done using your function signature.